# SwiftUI crash Crashlytics reported

Tags: swiftui, crashlytics

I am receiving a crash to Firebase Crashlytics:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  AttributeGraph                 0x5004 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 224
1  AttributeGraph                 0x5518 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 328
2  AttributeGraph                 0xa718 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 360
3  AttributeGraph                 0x1b3c0 AGGraphGetValue + 228
4  SwiftUI                        0xa4fdc specialized DynamicBody.phase.getter + 28
5  SwiftUI                        0xaada0 specialized DynamicBody.updateValue() + 56
6  SwiftUI                        0x20f9c0 partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 40
7  AttributeGraph                 0x5108 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
8  AttributeGraph                 0x5518 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 328
9  AttributeGraph                 0xa1a8 AG::Graph::value_ref(AG::AttributeID, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*) + 152
10 AttributeGraph                 0x1b408 AGGraphGetValue + 300
11 SwiftUI                        0x439378 ViewGraph.sizeThatFits(_:) + 212
12 SwiftUI                        0x439194 ViewGraph.updateIdealSize() + 48
13 SwiftUI                        0x438fc0 ViewGraph.updateOutputs(at:) + 108
14 SwiftUI                        0x84eef4 closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 1332
15 SwiftUI                        0x84ae68 ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 292
16 SwiftUI                        0x3395a0 closure #1 in _UIHostingView.requestImmediateUpdate() + 68
17 SwiftUI                        0x9a2190 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x602b0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x61298 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x43430 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 872
21 CoreFoundation                 0x9a998 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
22 CoreFoundation                 0x94df8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2528
23 CoreFoundation                 0x93ed0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
24 GraphicsServices               0x3570 GSEventRunModal + 160
25 UIKitCore                      0xb302d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052
26 UIKitCore                      0xb3584c UIApplicationMain + 164
27 SwiftUI                        0x881530 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 108
28 SwiftUI                        0x8814c0 runApp<A>(_:) + 176
29 SwiftUI                        0x432870 static App.main() + 96
30 ShopmonkeyApp                  0xf144 main + 4297568580 (<compiler-generated>:4297568580)
31 libdyld.dylib                  0x1140 start + 4
```

But there is no specific place where it's crashing. Has anybody faced the same crash?